# Binwalk and ext filesystem

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, ext4

i'm using binwalk with a binary file and i've found this string

```
Linux EXT filesystem, rev 0.0, ext4 filesystem data,...
```

With this command

```
binwalk -e binary.bin
```

I obtain a file called `4F592.ext`: how can i read it?
thanks

Comment: Try to mount it using `mount -o loop 4F592.bin someDirectory`...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to open ext4-files in Linux is to mount them as filesystems:

```
    sudo mount -o ro,loop 4F592.ext $(mktemp -d) # Mount into random directory
```